# What is the probability that a randomly selected 18-ounce bag of chocolate chip cookies contains fewer than 1300 chocolate chips?

Tags: statistics

I have no idea where to start on this question or where to begin to find the answer.  And I'm not sure how to calculate the probability.

Here is the full question:

The number of chocolate chips in an 18-ounce bag of chocolate chip cookies is normally distributed with a mean of 1238 chocolate chips and a standard deviation of 122 chocolate chips.  What is the probability that a randomly selected 18-ounce bag of chocolate chip cookies contains fewer than 1300 chocolate chips?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the number of chips in a randomly chosen bag.  Then
$$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.  A basic fact about normal distribution is that then
$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$
has a standard normal distribution.  Now
$$P(X<1300)=P\Bigl(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}<\frac{1300-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)
  =P\Bigl(Z<\frac{1300-\mu}{\sigma}\Bigr)\ .$$
See if you can fill in the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and look up the required probability in a standard normal distribution table.

Answer (score 0):

The density of probability following a normal distribution is :
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}exp{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
Here $\mu=1238$ and $\sigma=122$

You want to know what's the probability for a chocolate bag to have less than 1300 chocolate chips so :
$$
p(X\leq 1300)=\int_{-\infty}^{1300}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}exp{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} ~dx
$$

For more information, click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: Not sure i understand this completely

Comment: Sorry, I did too fast and it was wrong. Is it better ?

Comment: I think i get it...